# Why df[[2,3,4]][2:4] works and df[[2:4]][2:4] does not in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

suppose we have a datarame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('...')
df
  0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 2 3 4 5
3 1 2 3 4 5
4 1 2 3 4 5
```

Why one approach is working and other returns syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because `2:4` is invalid syntax for accessing the keys/columns of a df:

```
In [73]:
df[[2:4]]
  File "<ipython-input-73-f0f09617b349>", line 1
    df[[2:4]]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is no different to if you defined a dict and tried the same syntax:

```
In [74]:
d = {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5}
d

Out[74]:
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}

In [76]:
d[[2:4]]

  File "<ipython-input-76-ea5d68adc389>", line 1
    d[[2:4]]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The `[]` syntax is used to access column labels that match, you can't pass a slice in a list to access a range of columns like this, it needs to be a list of values as you've already found

The newer methods such as `iloc`, `ix` and `loc` support slice ranges

What worked for you, initially selected the columns using the labels in a list:

```
In [77]:
df[[2,3,4]]

Out[77]:
   2  3  4
0  3  4  5
1  3  4  5
2  3  4  5
3  3  4  5
4  3  4  5
```

And then selected the rows via a slice:

```
In [79]:
df[[2,3,4]][2:4]

Out[79]:
   2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
print (df.ix[2:4,2:4])
   2  3
2  3  4
3  3  4
4  3  4
```

Comment: Sorry, my coleague comes to me. Now I see second answer, I think it is very nice explanation. I think the best is use for selecting functions like [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html), [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).